# jQuery datatables in qtip2 popup

Tags: jquery, datatables, qtip2

I would like to insert the jQuery datatables table in a qtip2 popup.
I did this test:
http://jsfiddle.net/fDavN/5588/

But the search and pagination are not shown.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.btn-layer').each(function() {    
    $(this).qtip( {
        content: {
            text: 'Loading...',            
            title: {
                text: 'User',
                button: true
            },
            ajax: {
                url: '/echo/json/',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'text',
                cache: false,                
                //dataType: 'json',
                //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                //dataType: 'json',
                //data: { id: c_id },
                success: function(data) {
                    //var data = eval('(' + data + ')');                                        
                    data = testJson;                    
                    var $tab = $('<table class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable" id="tbl1"></table>');                                                               
                    $($tab).dataTable({                    
                        "aaData": data.aaData,
                        "aoColumns": data.aoColumns
                    });
                    this.set('content.text', $($tab) );
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert('AJAX error!');
                } 
****


});
```

Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use jquery datatables lot and I think you problem is that you didn't add the element `<table class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable" id="tbl1"></table>` into your page. I did the change of your code but didn't get time to test it. you can have a try.

```
success: function(data) {
    //var data = eval('(' + data + ')');                                        
    data = testJson;                    

    $('<table class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable" id="tbl1"></table>').appendTo('body').dataTable({                    
        "aaData": data.aaData,
        "aoColumns": data.aoColumns
    });
    this.set('content.text', $($tab) );
},
```

Comment: First of all thanks! But it doesn't work. The dataTable obj should not be appended to the body, but appended to the qtip2 object. Doing so I duplicate the datatable obj in the body and in the qtip element.
The same initial behavior if I do:
var $tab = $('<table class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable" id="tbl1"></table>').appendTo('body');

Comment: Fell happy that it can be helpful, because I didn't test the code, sorry for that.

Comment: The dataTable is loaded in qtip2, but the div wrapper that contains the search and filter divs are not in the qtip2, but appended to the body. Maybe because I'm using this.set('content.text', $($tab) ). I need to move the dataTable wrapper and not only <table class=""* >. Using this.set('content.text', $('#'+ name +'_wrapper')) works!