# jQuery datatables show/hide one field in row

Tags: jquery, datatables

I load a jQuery datatables using JSON. One of the fields in a row is the legend. 
Basically, I would like to have a "show/hide" legend instead of having the full legend text.
What can I do?

Thanks!

Updated with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/fDavN/5592/

```
Please check code on jsfiddle (quite long)
```

Comment: First thing you can do is show us: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Thanks for replying! I updated the question with the example. Basically the field legend (one per row) could be very long and I would like to add a show/hide functionality, but I really don't know where I can "work"

Comment: You probably have to do some thing like (pseudo code): $('.yourFormElementsSelector').each do{ if this.value.length >X, apply hide and show on hover to this }

Comment: @Cort3z at the beginning I had in mind something similar, I'm doing this test right now (the table can have 150+ rows with very long text). Indeed, I preferred to interact with .dataTable object, but currently I'm not seeing other solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Daviddd I can see that it might potentially pose some performance issues, but you should try this first. Only fix performance if it does become a problem. You could just run that code on the callback, so you essentially only run it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want add this functionality to every row, you should check datatables documentation:
[show-hide](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/row_details.html)

In my project (server-side processing) I did it by call `sDefaultContent` (on first column) on `aoColumns` definition:

```
"aoColumns": [
    {
       "mDataProp": null,
       "sClass": "control center",
       "sDefaultContent": '<img src="some_image_url">'
    },
    //...
]
```

and prepare function which append some data to clicked row:

```
$('#datatables_selector').live( 'click', function () {
    var nTr = this.parentNode;
    var i = $.inArray( nTr, anOpen );
    if ( i === -1 ) {
        $('img', this).attr( 'src', "some_image_url" );
        var nDetailsRow = oTable.fnOpen( nTr, fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr), 'details' );
        $('div.innerDetails', nDetailsRow).slideDown();
        anOpen.push( nTr );
    }
    else {
        $('img', this).attr( 'src', "some_image_url" );
        $('div.innerDetails', $(nTr).next()[0]).slideUp( function () {
            oTable.fnClose( nTr );
            anOpen.splice( i, 1 );
        } );
    }
} );
function fnFormatDetails( oTable, nTr ){
    var oData = oTable.fnGetData( nTr );
    var sOut = 'some html for input data: <div>, <table> etc';
    return sOut;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It solved my problem. I'm struggling with this since days: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267790/jquery-datatables-in-qtip2-popup, maybe :)